# Library management and search paths on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, g++, sdl-2, sdl-image

I created a simple program that shows an image (bmp) file but now I would like to load a jpg file and I found the "SDL_image" library that seems to do what I need, the dmg file I have mounted, contains a file SDL2_image.framework and a readme.txt reading the readme.txt I see:

> To Install: Copy the SDL2_image.framework to /Library/Frameworks
>
> You may alternatively install it in <your home
>   directory>/Library/Frameworks if your access privileges are not high
>   enough. (Be aware that the Xcode templates we provide in the SDL
>   Developer Extras package may require some adjustment for your system
>   if you do this.)

My questions are:

1. is g++ searching in "/Library/Frameworks" and "MYHOME/Library/Framework" inside all the frameworks files in order to find the libraries I include in my cpp files?
2. ones the g++ has built the executable file, do I still need those frameworks/libraries in order to execute it?
3. if instead of the framework file I use the sources of SDL2_Image library what is going to change to the process?